# Contact form not sending dropdown values

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, html-select, contact-form

I have created a contact form with dropdown values, as below, but the values aren't sent to my email - the rest of the values get sent through except for the dropdown values. Any help regarding this will be much appreciated, as I have done research that doesn't seem to help.

```js
Here is my JS

submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
    // get values from FORM
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var radio = $("input#radio").val();
    var message = $("textarea#message").val();
    var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
    // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
    if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
      firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    }
    $.ajax({
          url: "assets/contact_me.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            name: name,
            radio: radio,
            email: email,
            message: message,
            submit: 1
          },
```

```css
Here is my PHP <?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  var_dump($_POST);
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $radio=$_POST['radio'];
  $message=$_POST['message'];
  $mailTo="info@margineco.com";
  $subject="New message from ".$name;
  $headers="From: ".$email;
  $txt="You have received an email from ".$name." with regards to ".$radio.".\n\n".$message;
  mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
  header("Location: index.html?mailsend");
}

?>
```

```html
Here is my HTML

<div class="row control-group">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
    <label>Plan Option<span>*</span></label>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <select class="form-control" id="radio" required data-validation-required-message="Please choose a option from the dropdown menu.">
        <option type="radio" value="0" selected>Please select...</option>
        <option type="radio" value="option1">General Inquiry</option>
        <option type="radio" value="option2">Market Intelligence</option>
        <option type="radio" value="option3">Economic Analysis</option>
        <option type="radio" value="option4">Industry Forecasts</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <p class="help-block"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `input#radio` is not going to select any `select` field. (And `radio` is probably not the most sensible ID here to begin with.)

Comment: No need for a downvote here. The question is understandable and properly asked.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Maria ;)

First:

```
<option type="radio" value="option4">Industry Forecasts</option>
```

"type" is actually not a valid option for "option": https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option Should be:

```
<option value="option4">Industry Forecasts</option>
```

Second:

```
var radio = $("input#radio").val();
```

will not give you any result since you want to select from "select" and not from "input". Should be:

```
var radio = $("select#radio").val();
```

Comment: Hi Schlicki, thank you for the welcome and thank you for your suggestion! I've implemented your suggestion and it works! Thank you so much!
I'll remember this for next time :)